# Validate a string containing 1, 2, 3, or 4 fields?

Tags: c++, regex

I need some help building a regular expression for a string which may contain 1, 2, 3, or 4 fields. Each field has a format of: tag=value.

Below is a comprehensive list of all possible strings I can have. code tag is a three-digits number:

```
type=buy&code=123&time=yes&save=yes
type=buy&code=123&time=yes&save=no
type=buy&code=123&time=no&save=yes
type=buy&code=123&time=no&save=no
type=buy&code=123&time=yes
type=buy&code=123&time=no
type=sell&code=123&time=yes&save=yes
type=sell&code=123&time=yes&save=no
type=sell&code=123&time=no&save=yes
type=sell&code=123&time=no&save=no
type=sell&code=123&time=yes
type=sell&code=123&time=no
type=long&code=123
type=short&code=123
type=fill&code=123
type=confirm&code=123
type=cancelall
type=resendall
```

So these are the possible values for the four tags:

```
type={buy|sell|long|short|fill|confirm|cancelall|resendall}
code=[[:digit:]]{3}
time={yes|no}
save={yes|no}
```

This is what I have right now:

```
value={buy|sell|long|short|fill|confirm|cancelall|resendall}&code=[[:digit:]]{3}&time={yes|no}&save={yes|no}
```

It is obviously not correct, I do not know how make number of fields to be variable.

I want to use regular expression to check if the string is in correct format from C++ code. I am already doing it by parsing the string and using multiple "if" statements which makes tens of lines of code and it is also error prone.

Thank you!

Comment: Do they need to be in this order? Can any of them be omitted? Can some fields occur multiple times?

Comment: If this is an URL, there are better and even less errorprone ways to extract query parameters than regex. Please show us your attempts with the if-statements.

Comment: "Below I listed all possible variants of a string:" -- where "all", Bergi, means that fields must be in that order, fields 2,3, and 4 can be omitted in certain cases and I showed when, they cannot occur multiple times... Bergi...

Comment: I didn't take your "all" for serious since the *all possible variants* don't match the *all possible values*. Or do these examples (?) really mean that `save` only may exist when `time=yes`, that `time` may only exist for `buy` and `sell` types, and that there may not be a `code` for `cancelall` and `resendall` types?

Comment: I updated the examples, now there are really all :)

Comment: And the code must always be exactly `123`? Examples are nice, but what we really need are the *rules* you want for the regex.

Comment: So yes, for type=buy and type=sell must be four or three fields present, for type=long, short, fill, confirm must be only two fields present, for type=cancelall and type=resendall there is only a single field.

Comment: "code=[[:digit:]]{3}" code is a three digits number.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This regex will do it:

```
/^type=(?:(?:buy|sell)&code=\d{3}&time=(?:yes|no)(?:&save=(?:yes|no))?|(?:long|short|fill|confirm)&code=\d{3}|cancelall|resendall)$/
```

(using two [anchors](http://www.regular-expressions.info/anchors.html), an [optional item](http://www.regular-expressions.info/optional.html) and lots of [alternations](http://www.regular-expressions.info/alternation.html) in [non-capturing groups](http://www.regular-expressions.info/brackets.html))

> I am already doing it by parsing the string and using multiple "if" statements

For checking rules, this might be the better alternative. You still might use regexes for tokenizing your string.

You also might want to have a look at a [parser generator](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parser_generator), since you already seem to have a grammar available. The generator will yield parser code from that, which can be called to check the validity of your inputs and will return helpful error messages.

Comment: Bergi, it looks promising but the online regex tester does not show any matches. I am using regex101.com. I am trying to adapt it now but not there yet.

Comment: Demo: http://regex101.com/r/yB2oU6/1 (to match multiple lines in that textarea, you need the `g` and `m` flags).

Comment: I have tens of lines of code checking for the rules, I am hoping with regex to check if the string is in correct format in a "one" liner. Unfortunately I cannot post the code because it is for my job.

Comment: Sorry, if you can't post the code, we can't help you with it. Maybe talk to your boss about publicating parts of it.

Comment: Sorry, replied before tested properly, the regex gives false positive for the string "type=buy&code=123" where time=yes/no is necessary.

Comment: Oops, I didn't get that it was necessary. However, the fix is trivial :-)